# O365 : How to start Sharepoint site workflow using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365, designer-workflow

I am trying to start a site workflow(2013) created on my site using the below code.

```
function StartWorkflow(subscriptionId){
var params = new Object();
params = {param1:'<param1>'};
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var wfManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx,
ctx.get_web());
var subscription = 
wfManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subscriptionId);
ctx.load(subscription, 'PropertyDefinitions');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender, args)
    {
        wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflow(subscription, params);

    },
            function(sender, args)
            {
                alert('error');
            });

   }            

   var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";    
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.WorkflowServices.js", function () {
                        StartWorkflow('<subscriptionId>');
                    });
                });
            });
```

the code runs without any error but my workflow doesnt start.  However I am able to run a list workflow successfully using the above code by adding listID as 2nd parameter for startWorkflow method.  I assume that the subscriptionId is the templateId query string of the Workflow Initiation form URL

```
<sitename>/wfsvc/<someGUID>/WFInitForm.aspx?TemplateID={xxxxxxxx}&WF4=1&source=<url>
```

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflow(subscription, params);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
function (sender, args) { 
                 console.log("Successfully starting workflow."); },
function (sender, args) {
console.log("Failed to start workflow.");
console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
}
);
```

Try this `executeQueryAsync()` once again inside the `executeQueryAsync()`